# Help me build this tool in windows envoirnment

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop-application

I made a desktop music application in adobe air.

I want to update the status of some IM clients running EG: Yahoo messenger,Gtalk,AIM,MSN etc.
with the current playing song.
I am not desktop developer.This is first time i am making something for desktop.

SO is there any way in any Programming language that i can make something which will change the Data (Status message) of a running IM client.

Please Just guide me through this problem .

**Edit:** I dont want to ask for username/password of users IMs accounts , so via API is not a solution in this case .
It will be like Person X running mine music application and also logged to various third party IM clients (YIM,Gtalk etc).

SO if he is playing a song in the music application , then mine app will update presence status  message on the IM clients to " Listening to bla bla song ".
So it is like high-jacking/Hacking the data of the running third party IM client.

Comment: Is your google-fu failing that badly?

Comment: To my knowledge you have to target each IM client. There might be a framework that will allow you to target all at once.

Comment: @rubenvb may be yes , I have now idea what to search so i asked here.

Comment: @Chuck can you explain more on this how can i target a client , what language and API (etc) i should use/start with.

Comment: @Arsheep What IM client do you wish to target first?

Comment: Here is a good place to start: http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/

Comment: @chuck @everyone May be i failed to ask exact problem.
So i edited it again .Hope this makes sense now. :(

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple), it might have the functionality you require.

There is also [telepathy](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/), but I think it is related to the former somehow (one uses the other or they do the same thing).

**EDIT**: for the recent edit: it looks to me like you want something like MSN Messenger displaying the currently playing track in Windows Media Player. This requires a plugin for the messaging client, no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier way to get this done would be to develop a plugin for one of the numerous multi-platform IM clients such as GAIM or Trillian. This would let you target stuff across the board without undue effort . . .

Comment: +1 Nice suggestion but i fear it will target very less number of users.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is to write a plugin for each chat client you want to target, which could take some time.

So let me suggest an alternative: Add last.fm audioscrobbler support to your application. You would simply send the Now Playing info to last.fm via the API (http://www.last.fm/api/submissions), and it will appear on the user's profile page. Most music players already support this method because it's a pretty popular service, and a lot of people link to their last.fm profiles on their blog/facebook/etc.